# Causality and ROC of a stable LTI system

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, stability, causality

So I am looking at a stable LTI system whose input is $x[n]$ and output is $y[n]$. The equation relating the two is here:
$$
y[n-1]-\frac{10}{3}y[n]+y[n+1]=x[n]
$$

I was able to compute its system function $H(z)$ to be:
$$
H(z)=\frac{z^{-1}}{z^{-2}-\frac{10}{3}z^{-1}+1}
$$

I then performed partial fraction expansion to end up with:
$$
H(z)=\frac{\frac 38}{\left(1-3z^{-1}\right)} - \frac{\frac 38}{\left(1-\frac 13z^{-1}\right)}
$$

What I am struggling with is I can't decide what its ROC should be since the system is specified to be stable which means it has to include the $j\omega$-axis. I also need to determine if the system is causal or not. Since a system can only be causal and stable when all its poles are on the left hand plane, I am not sure.

Any help determining both the ROC and causality of the system would be very helpful.

Comment: You should be talking about "unit circle" instead of $j\omega$-axis, because we're in discrete time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like homework, so I'll give you a hint to help you figure this out by yourself.

There are 2 poles: one at $z=3$ (i.e., outside the unit circle) and one at $z=\frac13$ (i.e., inside the unit circle). For such a system there are three possible ROCs; one corresponds to an anti-causal system, another one to a causal system, and a third one to a non-causal system with a two-sided impulse response. But only one of those ROCs includes the unit circle, and that's the ROC corresponding to a stable system.

Comment: Okay yes so the ROC can be either |z| > 3, |z| < (1/3) or (1/3) < |z| < 3. If to be stable the ROC must include the unit circle, then would the proper ROC be |z| < (1/3)? Because since its pole is in the unit circle it would include the unit circle?

Comment: Wait wait, actually would it have to be the (1/3) < |z| < 3 ROC because then the system is bounded and includes the unit circle but remains stable!?

Comment: @user28308: Including the unit circle means that $|z|=1$ must be part of the ROC. So I guess you got it right.

Comment: So does the stable ROC of (1/3) < |z| < 3, make the system non-causal?

Comment: @user28308: A causal system always has a ROC specified by $|z|>R$ with some real-valued $R$. Think of the Z-transform as a power series. If for a causal sequence this series converges for some $|z|=c$ then it must also converge for all $|z|>c$ (since the series has only negative powers of $z$).

Comment: Okay so it'd be safe to say the system is causal

Comment: @user28308: Not the stable one, that one has a two-sided impulse response.

Comment: As I said before, a causal system has a ROC $|z|>R$ and NOT $r>|z|>R$.

Comment: Okay, you're incredibly helpful, if you wouldn't mind me asking one last thing: the system isn't minimum-phase, so how would you find the minimum-phase system for it?

Comment: @user28308: It's probably better if you ask that in a separate question. And make sure to express clearly what you exactly mean by "find the minimum-phase system for it".